# What is an engine in the context of object oriented design?

Tags: oop

Everywhere one can read about all kind of engines (game engine, view engine rules engine...). Do Somebody know the definition of what an engine is? Is it a design pattern?

Comment: There isn't one really. Think of the "engine" as being a subjective term for the bit of a program that does the real work; that's not directly concerned with input or output.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please specify the reason of your down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A software module is often called engine if it does a great deal of the work (calculation) but does not directly interact with the user.

The term is an analogy to a car engine that provides the power to move the car although the user (driver) does not have to know very much about it.

The term is not specific to OOP, however most engines are implemented as a collection of classes.

An engine is not a design pattern because it is too unspecific and not restricted to OOP. It is somewhat related to the *layered architecture* pattern where the lower layers often can be seen as the engine.